# Trying to pull data from the S&P 500 and I get an error on LMT. Is there a way to bypass that ticker and go to the next one?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am having trouble pulling data from the S&P500.  The code I have runs but once I get to LMT(lockheed Martin)I get a remote data error.  Is there a wway o fix this or can I just do a work around and have pyhton get the next tickers info?

```
     def get_data_from_google(reload_sp500=False):
            if reload_sp500:
                tickers = save_sp500_tickers()
            else:
                    with open ("sp500tickers.pickle","rb") as f:
                        tickers = pickle.load(f)

            if not os.path.exists('stock_dfs'):
                os.makedirs('stock_dfs')

                start = dt.datetime(2000,1,1)
                end = dt.datetime(2016,12,20)

                for ticker in tickers:
                    while True:
                        try:
                            x = int(input('LMT'))
                            break
                        except ValueError:
                            print('L')

                    print (ticker)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Cody/Desktop/S&P500 retrival.py", line 48, in <module>
    get_data_from_google()
  File "C:/Users/Cody/Desktop/S&P500 retrival.py", line 43, in get_data_from_google
    df = pdr.DataReader(ticker, 'google', start,end)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\data.py", line 137, in DataReader
    session=session).read()
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\base.py", line 181, in read
    params=self._get_params(self.symbols))
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\base.py", line 79, in _read_one_data
    out = self._read_url_as_StringIO(url, params=params)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\base.py", line 90, in _read_url_as_StringIO
    response = self._get_response(url, params=params)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\base.py", line 139, in _get_response
    raise RemoteDataError('Unable to read URL: {0}'.format(url))
pandas_datareader._utils.RemoteDataError: Unable to read URL: http://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=LMT&startdate=Jan+01%2C+2000&enddate=Dec+20%2C+2016&output=csv
```

Comment: What's the error? Can you show a stacktrace?

Comment: RemoteDataError('Unable to read URL: {0}'.format(url))
pandas_datareader._utils.RemoteDataError: Unable to read URL: http://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=LMT&startdate=Jan+01%2C+2000&enddate=Dec+20%2C+2016&output=csv

Comment: Please put the error/stacktrace into the body of your question.

Comment: Looks like a server-side issue.

Comment: okay.  Is there a way I can work around this.  How can I go to the next ticker symbol?

Comment: Catch the `RemoteDataError` exception in a `try/except` block.